# Crash after sending a message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

my discord.js bot  works  but  crashes after sending a reply, why?

using the example provided on the website and it does  not  work

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot ready`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');

});
```

help me  fix it please, thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific about "crashes after sending a reply". What does it mean crash? What kind of errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  missing  the closing bracket in the if condition

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot ready`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
}

});
```

should fix  it